# MathProg (AMPL) - Variable Array Sized by Another Variable

Tags: ampl, mathprog

I am writing my first GNU MathProg (AMPL) program to find the minimum switch (vertex) count instances of a HyperX topology (graph) for a given radix, number of hosts, and bisection bandwidth.  This is a simple first program because all of the equations have been described in the following paper: http://cal.snu.ac.kr/files/2009.sc.hyperx.pdf

I have read the specification and example programs, but I am stuck on a very simple syntax error.  I need to have the following two variables: L, the number of dimensions in the network, and an array S of length L, where each element of S is the number of switches in each dimension.  In my MathProg program, I express this as:

```
var L >= 1, integer;
var S{1 .. L} >= 2, integer;
```

However, when I run `$ glpsol --check --math hyperx.mod`, I get the following error:

```
hyperx.mod:28: operand following .. has invalid type
Context: ...isec ; param radix ; var L >= 1 , integer ; var S { 1 .. L }
```

If anybody can help explain how I should properly express this relationship, I will be grateful.  Also, I am including the entire program I have written for reference and extra help. I expect there to be many syntax errors in my program, but until I fix the first one, I have no way of finding the rest.

```
/* 
 * A MathProg linear program to find an optimal HyperX topology of a
 *  given network size, switch radix, and bisection bandwidth.  Optimal
 *  is simplistically defined as minimum switch count network. 
 *
 * A HyperX topology is a multi-dimensional network (graph) where, in
 *  each dimension, the switches are fully connected.  Every switch
 *  (vertex) is a point in an L-dimensional integer lattic.  Each switch
 *  is identified by a multi-index I = (I_1, ..., I_L) where 0 <= I_k <
 *  S_k for each k = 1..L, where S_k is the number of switches in each
 *  dimension.  A switch connects to all others whose multi-index is the
 *  same in all but one coordinate.
 */

/* Network size in number of hosts. */
param hosts;

/* Desired bisection bandwidth. */
param bisec;

/* Maximum switch radix. */
param radix;

/* The number of dimensions in the HyperX. */
var L >= 1, integer;

/* The number of switches in each dimension. */
var S{1 .. L} >= 2, integer;

/* 
 * Relative bandwidth of the dimension, i.e., the number of links in a
 * given dimension. 
 */
var K{1 .. L} >= 1, integer;

/* The number Terminals (hosts) per switch */
var T >= 1, integer;

/* Minimize the total number of switches. */
minimize cost: prod{i in 1..L} S[i];

/* The total number of links must be less than the switch radix. */
s.t. Radix: T + sum{i in 1..L} K[i] * (S[i] - 1) <= radix;

/* There must be enough hosts in the network. */
s.t. Hosts: T * prod{i in 1..L} S[i] >= hosts;

/* There must be enough bandwidth. */
s.t. Bandwidth: min{K[i]*S[i]} / (2 * T) >= bisec;

/* The order of the dimensions doesn't matter, so constrain them */
s.t. SwitchDimen: forall{i in 1..(L-1)} S[i] <= S[i+1];

/* 
 * Bisection bandwidth depends on the smallest S_i * K_i, so we know
 * that the smallest switch count dimension needs the most links.
 */
s.t. LinkDimen: forall{i in 1..(L-1)} K[i] >= K[i+1];

# TODO: I would like to constrain the search such that the number of
# terminals, T, is bounded to T >= (hosts / O), where O is the switch
# count of the smallest switch count topology discovered so far, but I
# don't know how to do this.

/* Data section */
data;

param hosts := 32

param bisec := 0.5

param radix := 64

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed number of variables in a problem is a common assumption in solvers and algebraic modelling languages including AMPL/MathProg. Therefore you can only use constant expressions, in particular parameters, not variables in indexing expressions. One possible solution is to make `L` a parameter, resolve your problem for different values of `L` and select the one that gives the best objective value. This can be done with a simple AMPL script.